# Django calling API from view and nested POST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do a POST method into the api from another project.

Firstly, i do a post to create appointment. If appointment success, i will post the current user profile into the Patient table from another project.

How do i do a POST in a POST and also how to post the current user information ?
I tried to do it, as shown below on my code but its just bad.

The field i am posting into Patient table.
My user profile field ---> Patient table
`userId` > `patientId`
`first_name` > `first_name`
`last_name` > `last_name`
`email` > `email`

Here is my code:

views:

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

    # request method to api from another project
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        print(data)

        # Have to post the user profile information into Patient table in another project.
        user_profile_attrs = {
            "patientId": self.request.userId,
            "first_name": self.request.first_name,
            "last_name": self.request.last_name,
            "username": self.request.username,
            "email": self.request.email,
        }
        # save into patient table of another project
        save_profile = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/patient/', data=request.POST)


        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
    else:
        return HttpResponse(r.text)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: use import requests as req and req.post(/../patient, params=request.POST)

Comment: @Vaibhav that won't make any difference.

Comment: All the `self.request.xxx` are in red line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

issues

1. requests.get passes arguments in `params` not in `data`. for detail [click here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)
2. use `request.POST.get('userId')` to get data from request, not `request.userId`

...

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', params=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        print(data)

        # Have to post the user profile information into Patient table in another project.
        user_profile_attrs = {
            "patientId": request.POST.get('userId'),
            "first_name": request.POST.get('first_name'),
            "last_name": request.POST.get('last_name'),
            "username": request.POST.get('username'),
            "email": request.POST.get('email'),
        }
        # save into patient table of another project
        save_profile = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/patient/', data=request.POST)


        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
    else:
        return HttpResponse(r.text)
```

Comment: Damnit I missed that.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

# request method to api from another project
if request.method == 'POST':
    r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.POST)
    if r.status_code == 201:
        data = r.json()
        print(data)

        # Have to post the user profile information into Patient table in another project.
        user_profile_attrs = {
            "patientId": request.POST.get('userId'),  # or request.user.id
            "first_name": request.POST.get('first_name'),  # or request.user.first_name
            "last_name": request.POST.get('last_name'),  # or request.user.last_name
            "username": request.POST.get('username'),  # or request.user.username
            "email": request.POST.get('email'),  # or request.user.email
        }
        # save into patient table of another project
        save_profile = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/patient/', data=request.POST)

        return HttpResponse(r.text)
else:
    r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/makeapp/', data=request.GET)


if r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
    return HttpResponse(r.json())
else:
    return HttpResponse(r.text)
```

But you might be better using a class based view and splitting the `POST` and `GET` requests.

Also, remove `self.` as it has no meaning here.

[EDIT: Updated to access the request data correctly. If the user info isn't passed as args then the commented access is needed.
Modified due to @AneeshRS' answer]

Comment: Thank you for your help.